# Backendless event does not fire

Tags: java, android, events, backendless

In my Android app I use [Backendless](https://backendless.com/) to store my data online. I want to do something when a new `Point` object is saved but the `beforeCreate` event never gets triggered.

Bootstrap.java

```
public class Bootstrap implements IBackendlessBootstrap
{            
  @Override
  public void onStart()
  {
    Backendless.setUrl( "https://api.backendless.com" );
    Backendless.initApp( "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXXXXXX","v1");
    Backendless.Persistence.mapTableToClass( "Point", Point.class );
  }

  @Override
  public void onStop()
  {        
  }    
}
```

PointTableEventHandler.java:

```
@Asset( "Point" ) 
public class PointTableEventHandler extends com.backendless.servercode.extension.PersistenceExtender<Point>
{    
  @Override
  public void beforeCreate( RunnerContext context, Point point) throws Exception
  {
      System.out.println("enter beforeCreate");
      point.setPhoneNumber("12345");
      System.out.println("exit beforeCreate");
  }    
}
```

Point.java

```
public class Point extends BackendLessObject {
    private String phoneNumber;

    public Point() {
        super();
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }
}
```

BackendlessObject.java

```
public class BackendLessObject {

    protected String objectId;
    protected Date created;
    protected Date updated;
    protected String ownerId;

    public BackendLessObject() {    
    }

    public String getObjectId()  {
        return objectId;
    }

    public void setObjectId( String objectId )
    {
        this.objectId = objectId;
    }

    public Date getCreated()
    {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated( Date created )
    {
        this.created = created;
    }

    public Date getUpdated()
    {
        return updated;
    }

    public void setUpdated( Date updated )
    {
        this.updated = updated;
    }    

    public String getOwnerId() {
        return ownerId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return objectId;
    }
}
```

The event is enabled and deployed to production. When I run my app the point is created with all the data provided, but the `PhoneNumber` is not set - so the event did not run. Debugging it also shows that it was never called.

In my Android app I call

```
newPoint.save();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in the latest version of the library. Make sure to grab a copy from the [github repository](https://github.com/Backendless/Android-SDK/blob/master/out/backendless.jar).

Comment: I already tried that new lib. But it is still the same. I also wonder why my app still only compiles if I include the lib as `compile 'com.backendless:backendless:3.0.8.2'` instead of version `3.0.11` which says it is in the lib.